# Selection.EntireRow.Delete error where cells may be selected in multiple columns of the row?

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I need to delete selected rows in a template.

`Selection.EntireRow.Delete` handles all my scenarios, but one.

When I select the same row, in multiple selections `Selection.EntireRow.Delete` will throw a 1004 Error.

I've written an ErrorHandler to warn about the situation, and then resume to not leave the template unlocked.

```vb
Sub DelRows()

    Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult, LRow As Integer
    LRow = Range("D5").Value
    
    If Selection.Cells(1, 1).Row < 9 Or Selection.Cells(1, 1).Row + Selection.Rows.Count > LRow - 1 Then                                            
        MsgBox "Forbidden selection."
    ElseIf Selection.Rows.Count > LRow - 11 Then                                                                                                    
        MsgBox "Can't delete all rows."
    Else
        On Error GoTo ErrHandler
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="xx"
        answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete all rows?", vbOKCancel + vbExclamation, "Warning")
        If answer = 1 Then Selection.EntireRow.Delete                        
        Rows((LRow + 2) & ":1048576").EntireRow.Hidden = True                               
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="xx", DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
    
    End If
    Exit Sub

    ErrHandler:
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then
            MsgBox "Can't select the same row twice: " & Err.Description
            Resume Next
        Else
            MsgBox Err.Description
            Resume Next
    End If
End Sub
```

The thing works, but my experience with error handling isn't the best.

Can I avoid this error with some other  method?
Can I check the selection for multiple selections in the same row, or isn't it worth the effort of doing so?

I could probably loop all selected cells, create an array containing the rows for each area and then compare the results, but that seems excessive.

**--Final solution--**

Thanks to [Pᴇʜ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3219613/p%E1%B4%87%CA%9C) I managed to not only solve the problem, but find and solve two more at the same time.

Multiple selections break my `Selection.Cells(1, 1).Row` and `Selection.Rows.Count` as they only care about the first area. Which can both be fixed by looping the areas.

```vb
    Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult, LRow As Long, i As Long, RowCount As Long, TopRow As Long
    LRow = Range("D5").Value
    TopRow = Selection.Cells(1, 1).Row
    
    For i = 1 To Selection.Areas.Count
        RowCount = RowCount + Selection.Areas(i).Rows.Count
        If Selection.Areas(i).Cells(1, 1).Row < TopRow Then TopRow = Selection.Areas(i).Cells(1, 1).Row
    Next i
    
    If TopRow < 9 Or TopRow + RowCount > LRow - 1 Then                                         
        MsgBox "Forbidden selection."
    ElseIf RowCount > LRow - 11 Then                                                                                                    
        MsgBox "Can't delete all rows."
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="xx"
        answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete all rows?", vbOKCancel + vbExclamation, "Warning")
        If answer = 1 Then Selection.EntireRow.Delete                        
        Rows((LRow + 2) & ":1048576").EntireRow.Hidden = True                               
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="xx", DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
    
    End If
End sub
```

Comment: Note that you must declare `LRow As Long`. Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle! I recommend [always to use Long instead of Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613) in VBA since there is no benefit in `Integer` at all.

Comment: Good call. I've been slightly afraid of Long since I had to convert a few projects from 32bit to 64bit that used LongLong. I see now that this is not a problem and not the same thing. I'll stick to long in the future, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a trick and use the [Application.Union method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union)

```
Union(Selection.EntireRow, Selection).delete
```

This avoids the error of multiple selections in one row.

---

Edit according to comments:

```
Dim i As Long, RowCount As Long
For i = 1 To Selection.Areas.Count
    RowCount = RowCount + Selection.Areas(i).Rows.Count
Next i
```

Comment: Exactly the thing I was looking for. Works great!

Comment: I noticed that my `Selection.Rows.Count` doesn't work with multiple selections (only returning the first selection). So changed it to `Union(Selection.Rows, Selection).Count` instead which works much works better!  It does count the same row multiple times though. Something new for me to think about.

Comment: `Selection.Rows.Count` doesn't work because it only shows the row count of the first area that is selected. You must loop through the `Selection.Areas` and add all counts together. See my edit.

Comment: That's great. That solves the last two problems at once. I'll edit what I did into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit on the side, but I came over this post looking for error on delete selection on a filtered table. So maybe it may help someone else. If you are getting the error message "Deletion method of Range class failed". Run-time error '1004'.

I have a table in my worksheet named "Table_1". Selecting the table or a column in the table and then doing the `.EntireRow.Delete` syntax throws me an error. Selecting the full table, excluding header, and then just doing  `.Delete` works fine. Thus leaving the simple code:

```
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False   'To avoid the pop-up when delete the rows.
    Range("Table_1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Any filtering ect. you'll have to do in your normal way.

I hope this may help someone.

Thanks
BR
Fnk